# I cant complete the easiest Codewars challenge

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and can't figure out how to complete the easiest challenge in codewars. I feel so dumb :(

> Question: I have a cat and a dog.
>
> I got them at the same time as kitten/puppy. That was humanYears years
>   ago.
>
> Return their respective ages now as [humanYears,catYears,dogYears]

NOTES:

- humanYears >= 1
- humanYears are whole numbers only

Cat Years

- 15 cat years for first year
- +9 cat years for second year
- +4 cat years for each year after that

Dog Years

- 15 dog years for first year
- +9 dog years for second year
- +5 dog years for each year after that

This is my code:

```
def human_years_cat_years_dog_years(human_years):
    catYears = 0
    dogYears = 0

    if human_years == 1:
        catYears = 15
        dogYears = 15

    elif human_years == 2:
        catYears = 24
        dogYears = 24

    elif human_years >= 3:
        catYears = 4*human_years + 24 
        dogYears= 5*human_years + 24

    return [human_years, catYears, dogYears]
```

I know that my problems lies in the >= 3 part. I just can't figure out how to make it right unless I make an IF statement for every integer above 3.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to take out the first 2 years when doing the >= 3 years

```
def human_years_cat_years_dog_years(human_years):
    catYears = 0
    dogYears = 0

    if human_years == 1:
        catYears = 15
        dogYears = 15

    elif human_years == 2:
        catYears = 24
        dogYears = 24

    elif human_years >= 3:
        catYears = 4*(human_years-2) + 24 
        dogYears= 5*(human_years-2) + 24


    return [human_years, catYears, dogYears]
```

Answer (score 0):

Different implementation, worse time complexity, but maybe more flexible if you want to add other animals or more complicated aging ( like 15,9,4,3,3,3,3,2,1)

```
def years(human, arr):
    return sum( arr[min(i,len(arr)-1)] for i in range(human))

def human_years_cat_years_dog_years(human_years):
    cat = [15,9,4]
    dog = [15,9,5]
    return human_years, years(human_years,cat), years(human_years,dog)
```